# How to handle very large integers in python?

Tags: python, anaconda, largenumber

I wrote a code for getting the Fibonacci sequence, using the concept of the Fibonacci matrix, inspired from this Instagram post

[image]

```
def f(n):
import numpy as np
m=np.array([[1,1],[1,0]],dtype=np.int64)
m1=m
for i in range(0,n):
    m1=np.matmul(m1,m)
return m1[0,1]
```

but after n=93, it starts to give negative numbers. If I use np.int32 as dtype then after n=47, it starts to give negative and erroneous results.
I am using python 3.9 and I want my result to be integers(not float) what to do so that I can get correct results for n=1000 or larger?

Answer (score 1):

Numpy ctypes are implemented natively, so a long datatype will start overflowing when reaching 64 bits. However, you can use `dtype=object` to use python's arbitrarily large integers, this could get quite slow to process though.

Comment: oh sorry, that was a mistake, actually, i was using np.int64, in python 3.9, it says there is nothing called long.
I used dtype=object, and then this code
for i in range(1,100):
    print(f(i-1))
    if f(i-1)<0:
        print(i)
        break

but still at i=93, it gives negative number

Comment: which index gives you a negative number? I just tried `print([f(i) for i in range(0, 1000)])` and nothing is negative. Assuming the code was updated to `m=np.array([[1,1],[1,0]], dtype=object)`